# Login with facebook sdk shared preference and get information about user

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

i am developing an app where facebook login is there . i am trying to get user information and send that to my server.i am using sdk 4.i am trying to use shared preference to save info but i have no idea about shared preference . This is my facebook login activity . this is launcher activity.

```
public class LoginActivity extends  AbsRuntimePermission {
private static final int REQUEST_Permission =10;


    private TextView info;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private SparseIntArray mErrorString;
    private Button facebook_button;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    private String facebook_id,f_name,m_name,l_name,gender,profile_image,full_name,email_id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    //for permission in manifest file cause it is launch activity

    requestAppPermissions(new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET},R.string.msg,REQUEST_Permission);

    //facebook
    info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    progress = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
    progress.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait_facebooklogin));
    progress.setIndeterminate(false);
    progress.setCancelable(false);

    facebook_id=f_name=m_name=l_name=gender=profile_image=full_name=email_id="";

    //facebook sdk
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    //register callback object for facebook result

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            progress.show();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            if(profile != null){
                facebook_id = profile.getId();
                f_name=profile.getFirstName();
                m_name=profile.getMiddleName();
                l_name=profile.getLastName();
                profile_image=profile.getProfilePictureUri(400,400).toString();
            }
            //show Toast
            GraphRequest request =GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback(){
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            try {
                                email_id = object.getString("email");
                                gender = object.getString("gender");
                                String Profile_name = object.getString("name");
                                long fb_id = object.getLong("id"); //use this for logout

                                //Starting a new activity using this information
                                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                i.putExtra("type", "facebook");
                                i.putExtra("Facebook_id", facebook_id);
                                i.putExtra("f_name", f_name);
                                i.putExtra("m_name", m_name);
                                i.putExtra("l_name", l_name);
                                i.putExtra("full_name", full_name);
                                i.putExtra("Profile_image", profile_image);
                                i.putExtra("email_id", email_id);
                                i.putExtra("gender", gender);

                                progress.dismiss();
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();

                            }catch (JSONException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,getResources().getString(R.string.login_canceled_facebooklogin),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progress.dismiss();
        }

        @Override

        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,getResources().getString(R.string.login_failed_facebooklogin),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    });

    //facebook button click
    facebook_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile","user_friends","email"));

        }
    });
}

private void logoutFromFacebook(){
    try{
        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()==null){
            return;
        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}

@Override
public void onPermissionGranted(int requestCode) {

    //anything after permission Granted
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}



public void goTo(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: please share your error log

Comment: @ShaileshLimbadiya sir now i have fixed that error ... now problem is i am unable to jump to my next activity when login completes plus it does not save anything inside shared preferences http://pastebin.com/py23Gtqf check my full code here .

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Android SharedPreferences allows us to store private primitive
>   application data in the form of key-value pair.For More details follow [this](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sharedpreferences-tutorial-and-example/).

To read from shared preference use something like this.

```
String dateFromSharedPreferences=getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPref.getString("Username");
```

To save into shared preference

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("Username", YourUsername);
    editor.putString("Password", YourPassword);
    editor.apply();
```

You are passing the values from `LoginActivity` to `MainActivity` so code in `MainActivity` at `onCreate` function like following to get the passed values ans show in textview.

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1)).setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("full_name"));
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2)).setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("email_id"));
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3)).setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("gender"));
```

Comment: @kuldeepraj so send me the log now

Comment: add this line `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));`

before `LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback`

Comment: @jafarbech still app crashes :(

Comment: u r now developer @kuldeepraj dont say that app crashes... it happens 1000 of times... u have to be clear one by one. first accept the answer. we ll chat in the chat room

Comment: bro i have accepted your answer but still facing some issues ... can we chat ?? now app is not crashing.. i have fixed that ... but facing issue regarding shared preferences

Comment: Come to the same group

Comment: Bro can we chat like in personal ... i am unable to find that group @jafarbtech

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129315/discussion-between-jafarbtech-and-kuldeep-raj).

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

Write this code before going to intent.

```
sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("User_Name", f_name);
            editor.putString("User_Email", email_id);
            editor.apply();
```

Comment: i have followed this tutorial http://www.coders-hub.com/2014/07/how-to-add-facebook-sdk-in-android.html#.WDvxyaJ96DU

Comment: can you please tell me in logoutFromFacebook why i am unable to get getFacebookId ???

Answer (score 0):

I know this type of question so many answer but still i am give this question's answer, I hope some one got the help. It's easy if we create method to handle all data.
When receive facebook JSON object then after do as follow.

```
try {
        Bundle bFacebookData = getFacebookData(object);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        progressDialog.cancel();
        setSessionData(bFacebookData);

    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

//here you can get all facebook data and store in bundle

```
private Bundle getFacebookData(JSONObject object)
    {
        try {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            //String id = object.getString("id");

            try
            {
                URL profile_pic = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + object.getString("id") + "/picture?width=200&height=150");
                Log.i("profile_pic", profile_pic + "");
                if (profile_pic.toString() != null)
                {
                    bundle.putString("profile_pic", profile_pic.toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    bundle.putString("profile_pic", "noProfilePic");
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

            if (object.has("id"))
            {
                if (object.getString("id") != null)
                {
                    bundle.putString("userId", object.getString("id"));
                    Log.i(TAG, "Info " + object.getString("id"));
                }
                else
                {
                    bundle.putString("userId", "noUserId");
                    Log.i(TAG, "Info " + object.getString("id"));
                }
            }
            if (object.has("first_name"))
            {
                if (object.getString("first_name") != null)
                {
                    bundle.putString("first_name", object.getString("first_name"));
                    Log.i(TAG + "Info", object.getString("first_name"));
                }
                else
                {
                    bundle.putString("first_name", "noFirstName");
                    Log.i(TAG + "Info", object.getString("first_name"));
                }
            }
            if (object.has("last_name"))
            {
                if (object.getString("last_name") != null)
                {
                    bundle.putString("last_name", object.getString("last_name"));
                    Log.i(TAG + "Info", object.getString("last_name"));
                }
                else
                {
                    bundle.putString("last_name", "noLastName");
                    Log.i(TAG + "Info", object.getString("last_name"));
                }
            }

            if (object.has("email"))
            {
                if (object.getString("email") != null)
                {
                    bundle.putString("email", object.getString("email"));
                    Log.i(TAG + "Info", object.getString("email"));
                }
                else
                {
                    bundle.putString("email", "noEmail");
                    Log.i(TAG + "Info", object.getString("email"));
                }
            }


            //this is added dynamically
            bundle.putString("phone", "noPhone");

            if (object.has("gender"))
            {
                if (object.getString("gender") != null)
                {
                    bundle.putString("gender", object.getString("gender"));
                    Log.i(TAG + "Info", object.getString("gender"));
                }
                else
                {
                    bundle.putString("gender", "noGender");
                    Log.i(TAG + "Info", object.getString("gender"));
                }
            }

            if (object.has("birthday"))
            {
                if (object.getString("birthday") != null)
                {
                    bundle.putString("birthday", object.getString("birthday"));
                    Log.i(TAG + "Info", object.getString("birthday"));
                }
                else
                {
                    bundle.putString("birthday", "noDateOfBirth");
                    Log.i(TAG + "Info", object.getString("birthday"));
                }
            }

            if (object.has("location"))
            {
                if (object.getJSONObject("location").getString("name") != null)
                {
                    bundle.putString("location", object.getJSONObject("location").getString("name"));
                    Log.i(TAG + "Info", object.getJSONObject("location").getString("name"));
                }
                else
                {
                    bundle.putString("location", "noLocation");
                    Log.i(TAG + "Info", object.getJSONObject("location").getString("name"));
                }
            }

            return bundle;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

//here you can store data in SharedPreferences and start new activity

```
String userId = "", userEmail = "", userFirstName = "", userLastName = "",
            userPhone = "", dateOfBirth = "", gender = "", profilePic = "";

    private void setSessionData(Bundle bundle)
    {
        try
        {
            userId = bundle.getString("userId");
            userEmail = bundle.getString("email");
            userFirstName = bundle.getString("first_name");
            userLastName =  bundle.getString("last_name");
            userPhone = bundle.getString("phone");
            dateOfBirth =  bundle.getString("birthday");
            gender =  bundle.getString("gender");
            profilePic =  bundle.getString("profile_pic");

            if (userId !=null)
            {

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                editor.putString("userId", userId);
                editor.putString("email", userEmail);
                editor.putString("first_name", userFirstName);
                editor.putString("last_name", userLastName);
                editor.putString("phone", userPhone);
                editor.putString("birthday", dateOfBirth);
                editor.putString("gender", gender);
                editor.putString("profile_pic", profilePic);

                editor.apply();


                Intent i = new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                activity.startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
                //"Some thing went wrong Please try again"
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrach();
        }
    }
```

Your another class to receive data from SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);

((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1)).setText(sharedPreferences.getString("first_name", ""));
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2)).setText(sharedPreferences.getString("last_name", ""));
```